# The Integration of a Polynomial

Tags: java, math

I am having trouble implementing an integration function for one of my classes. Somewhere along the line, I'm screwing up the maths and I don't really understand where and why. I've included the functions that I came up with for creating the polynomial, printing it, and deriving it. Please let my know if anything else is a glaring issue.

*An example of the input is putting in an array {5,3,2} and the console would print 5.0x^2 + 3.0x^1 + 2.0 it does not print if the coefficient is 0 and it doesn't have a set size for the array **ALWAYS ASSUMING C = 0***

```
import mymath.Poly;
import mymath.PolyCalc;

public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Poly poly = new Poly(new double[]{5,3,2});

      poly.printPoly();

      poly = PolyCalc.integrate(poly);
      poly.printPoly();

   }
}
```

```
package mymath;

public class Poly
{
    protected double[] coefficents;
    private double x;


    public Poly(double[] coefficients)
    {
        this.coefficents = coefficients;
    }


    public void setX(double x) {this.x = x;}
    public double getX() {return x;}

    public void setCoefficents(double[] coefficents) {this.coefficents = coefficents;}
    public double[] getCoefficents() {return coefficents;}

    public double evaluate()
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < coefficents.length; i++)
        {
            sum += coefficents[i]*Math.pow(x,coefficents.length-1-i);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public void printPoly()
    {
        StringBuilder polynomial = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < coefficents.length; i++)
        {
            if(coefficents[i] != 0)
            {
                if(coefficents[i] <= 0)
                {
                    if(coefficents.length-i-1 != 0)
                    {
                        polynomial.append(" - ").append(-coefficents[i]).append("x^").append(coefficents.length - i - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        polynomial.append(" - ").append(-coefficents[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (coefficents.length-i-1 != 0)
                    {
                        polynomial.append(" + ").append(coefficents[i]).append("x^").append(coefficents.length - i - 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        polynomial.append(" + ").append(coefficents[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(polynomial.toString().trim().charAt(0) == '-')
        {
            System.out.println(polynomial.toString().trim());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(polynomial.toString().trim().substring(1).trim());
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class PolyCalc
{

    public static Poly differentiate(Poly polynomial)
    {
        double[] oldCoefficents = polynomial.coefficents;
        double[] newCoefficents = new double[oldCoefficents.length];
        newCoefficents[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < newCoefficents.length-1; i++)
        {
            newCoefficents[i+1] = oldCoefficents[i]*(oldCoefficents.length-1-i);
        }

        return new Poly(newCoefficents);
    }

    public static Poly integrate(Poly polynomial)
    {
        double[] oldCoefficents = polynomial.coefficents;
        double[] newCoefficents = new double[oldCoefficents.length+1];

        for (int i = newCoefficents.length-2; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            newCoefficents[i+1] = oldCoefficents[i]/(double)(i+1);
        }
        newCoefficents[newCoefficents.length-2] = 0;
        return new Poly(newCoefficents);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it isn't working? When you integrate an indefinite integral, wouldn't it still have an unknown constant?

Comment: It looks like your polynomial, the 0'th index is the largest exponent. When you do the integral, the smallest index has the smallest denominator. Create an actual variable to represent the powers and you'll see it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I got it I had to draw out diagrams and do the math in my head I believe this works.

```
public static Poly integrate(Poly polynomial)
    {
        double[] oldCoefficents = polynomial.coefficents;
        double[] newCoefficents = new double[oldCoefficents.length+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < newCoefficents.length-1; i++)
        {
            newCoefficents[i] = oldCoefficents[i]/ (double)(oldCoefficents.length-i);
        }

        return new Poly(newCoefficents);
    }
```

Thanks to everyone that helped out cheers